# A problem with certain glyphs in EB Garamond font

Tags: ebgaramond

I am setting a book using KOMA-Script and EB Garamond font. Mostly it works well, but there are certain fairly standard glyphs that just produce errors. E.g., neither \copyright not \textcopyright produce a copyright symbol, and \textonehalf and \textonequarter don't produce the corresponding numbers. Yet according to the font tables I have seen, EB Garamond includes these glyphs. I am using TeXLive in an openSuSe 13.2 installation. Am I doing something wrong, or do I need a different version of the font?

Comment: You should provide us with a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing your setup, how you've loaded this font, and demonstrating this problem. The solution is likely to be revealed that way and, if not, it'll give us something to experiment with at the least

Comment: +1 on MWE, I get those symbols with `\documentclass{scrartcl}` and `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` on a Mac.

Comment: On texlive 2015 I have no problem creating the symbols. I used `memoir`class and `scrrprt` as well as `scratcl`

Answer (score 3):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Do check if there's something missing or installed incorrectly in your TeX distribution. With a properly installed, up-to-date TeX distribution, the following code should compile equally well under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, *and* LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex} % load EB Garamond font
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\else
  \ifxetex  
    \usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
  \else   
    \usepackage{ebgaramond}
  \fi
\fi

\begin{document}
\copyright, \textcopyright, \textonehalf, \textonequarter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at the code of `ebgaramond.sty` I'd say that `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` is enough for all engines: the package properly checks for Xe/LuaTeX and loads `fontspec`, and sets up the font with more details than just `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`. But +1 anyway `:-)`

Comment: @campa - Thanks. I can't quite remember what I was thinking when I wrote this answer almost 2-1/2 years ago. I think that I was quite concerned that the OP possibly had a faulty TeX installation and hence that the tests for which engine is in use should be handled explicitly rather than via the package's built-in capabilities. Also, I seem to remember that the `ebgaramond` package didn't acquire the ability to check which engine is in use until sometime in late 2014. Given that I wrote this answer in early 2016, I didn't want to have to assume that the OP's TeX distribution was up to date.

Comment: Are the commands like `\textonehalf` listed somewhere? On the ctan page of the package a pdf of font samples is available and another pdf (http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ebgaramond/doc/EBGaramond-Regular-Glyphs.pdf) with all the glyphs is available. But how can one access those glyphs via commands like `\textonehalf` ?

Comment: @Damitr - I'm afraid I'm not enough of a font specialist to answer your question in adequate depth. May I suggest you post a *new query*, in which you'd ask your question for many more people to see (and hopefull come up with answers). Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion will create a new post.